# Xamarin Forms Android splash screen landscape orientation

Tags: android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement splash screen in portrait and landscape. Following link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen

I added two separate files SplashBackground.xml and SplashBackgroundLandscape.xml with correct images. Added values-land folder with separate style.xml. Still the landscape image is not displayed on rotation. Am I missing anything?
[image]

Below is the style.xml for landscape. Portrait is same with drawable name @drawable/splash_portrait

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
     <item    name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_landscape</item>
  </style>
 </resources>
```

Comment: Add to question the `xml` inside `values-land/styles.xml`. Importantly, did you modify it to refer to your **landscape drawable**? Also, I'm surprised the portrait verion works: AFAIK all `png` and `xml` file names should only use **lowercase** letters: `splash_background.xml` `splash_landscape.png`, etc.

Comment: I updated the names with lower case and pasted the style.xml code above. Still no luck. Portrait image renders correctly. If I rotate the device in landscape it stretches the portrait image then getting the landscape.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the item name "**splash_landscape**" is not same with "**splashbackgroundlandscape**",you may want to change that.
And below is my test sample solution structure you can take a look:

[image]

style(land):

[image]

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
          android:versionCode="1" 
          android:versionName="1.0" 
          package="com.companyname.myandroidtestapp">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:theme="@style/MyTheme" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" >
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: Do I need to update AndroidManifest.xml file? Where are you referencing MyTheme.Splash?

Comment: yes, check my update

Answer (score 0):

Please see the updated screenshot with lower case names
[image]

Code for splash_landscape.xml. It has correct image name - splash_bg_landscape

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <color android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
</item>
<item>
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/splash_bg_landscape" android:tileMode="disabled" android:gravity="center" />
</item>
```

Code for style.xml from values-land folder (for landscape mode)

```
<resources>
<style name="MainTheme" parent="MainTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash_landscape</item>
</style>
```

I feel everything is correct; however, when I deploy the app in landscape mode, it is not using the correct splash_bg_landscape image. App shows stretched portrait image. I am using Samsung device for testing.